# Add certificate to both server and client using WCF and gSOAP

Tags: c++, .net, wcf, ssl, gsoap

I have WCF web service that need to be secured using SSL/TLS protocol. In the other hand I have C++ client that consume WCF web service using [gSOAP library](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html). Already only server needs to have certificate. Now I have tasked to enforce client to have certificate. My earlier implementation for client is like this:

```
    soap_ssl_init();
    int soapResult = soap_ssl_client_context(soapPtr, SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION, "client.pem", NULL,
        NULL, "cacert.pem", NULL);
    if (soapResult)
    {
        soap_print_fault(soapPtr, stderr);
        throw new ClientLogException("Can not use ssl for comminucations!");
    }
    else
    {

    }

    struct soap mySoap = *soapPtr;
    WSHttpBinding_USCOREILogServicesProxy proxy(mySoap);
    input.request = &request;
    int callCode = proxy.CallWebService(WEB_SERVICE_ADDRESS, NULL, &input, response);
    if (callCode != 0)
    {
        cout << "Web service call code: " + callCode << endl;
        throw new ClientLogException("Error in calling web service with call code: " + callCode);
    }
```

which I does it from [gSOAP documents](https://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html). It works fine with only server required to have certificate. I viewed communication using WireShark and connection was completely encrypted.

Now for enforcing client to use certificate, I am going to use [Nine simple steps to enable X.509 certificates on WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36683/simple-steps-to-enable-X-certificates-on-WCF) article. But the article uses a C# WCF client. I must implement client configuration in my gSOAP C++ client. I can add client certificate in above code when calling `soap_ssl_client_context` and in third parameter.

I have 2 problem here:

1- I don't know is it possible calling web service that both client and server have certificates and communication be secured when server uses WCF and client uses gSOAP.

2- In the CodeProject article it seems that web service call is using **http** and I am wonder there is no encryption in communication.

In the end if anyone has better solution, or recommend other tools will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS works out of the box with gsoap if you compile with `-DWITH_OPENSSL` and link against the OpenSSL libs. The out-of-the-box default settings will encrypt messages with `https://`, but this does not enforce authentication because you need to register the server certificates first with `soap_ssl_client_context()` as you point out.

To authenticate both server and client, the [gsoap manual](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.22) suggests the following:

```
int soapResult = soap_ssl_client_context(soapPtr,
    SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT,  // requires server to authenticate
    "client.pem",      // client cert (+public key) to authenticate to server
    "password",        // you need this when client.pem is encrypted
    NULL,              // capath to certs, when used
    "cacert.pem",      // should contain the server cert
    NULL);
```

Also, you may need to convert [PEM to CER](http://www.genivia.com/tutorials.html#How_to_convert_certificates_in_PEM_format_to_CER_format_for_MS_Windows) (or the other way) for windows.